# Cannot persist to Cassandra with datanucleus on UUID

Tags: java, cassandra, uuid, datanucleus

I have a table with an ID field so defined:

```
create table XXX (
id uuid primary key,
name varchar,
....
```

and my class XXX is so annotated:

```
public class XXX {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(customValueStrategy = "uuid")
public UUID id;
...
```

When trying to issue a PersistenceManager.makePersistent(), I get:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Invalid Id generated for field XXX.id, id : 54e5abde-732b-42ff-af92-06af89af46ff
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:673)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:720)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:740)
>       at Importer.save(StayImporter.java:84)
>       at Importer.exec(StayImporter.java:102)
>       at Importer.main(Importer.java:110)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
>   Invalid Id generated for field XXX.id, id : 54e5abde-732b-42ff-af92-06af89af46ff
>   org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Invalid Id generated for field XXX.id, id : 54e5abde-732b-42ff-af92-06af89af46ff
>       at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.getStrategyValue(AbstractStoreManager.java:1300)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.populateStrategyFields(StateManagerImpl.java:2201)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.initialiseForPersistentNew(StateManagerImpl.java:418)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.initialiseForPersistentNew(StateManagerImpl.java:120)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.newForPersistentNew(ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.java:218)
>       at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2078)
>       at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectWork(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1922)
>       at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1777)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:715)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:740)

The UUID looks good to me, why does it not work?

Maven is:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
<artifactId>datanucleus-accessplatform-jdo-cassandra</artifactId>
<version>4.2.1</version>
<type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
<artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
<version>2.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Cassandra version is 2.2.3

Comment: I would have thought all generators are normally String or Integer based. What happens if you make that field a String? Also that is not the real exception ... will be nested

Comment: I have included the nested exception

Comment: With a String field, i get:

org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Invalid Id generated for XXX.id, id : 7aa194c8-06d2-491f-9ccb-4e52db36dd0a

Comment: I have no trouble using a String field with "uuid" generation

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: The same basic class does not work for me - your answer contains no information

Comment: It contains all info needed; I took a basic class with one String field ... PrimaryKey and ValueGenerator(uuid). As I said I let the persistence solution create the table .... it then has varchar in the PK column.

Comment: Since it contains all the information that's needed, i'll copy and paste it into eclipse,  to check if it works - i have doubts though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this forum post: http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,7922_lastpage,yes#lastpost

Excerpt from linked content:

> "UUIDGenerator" generates Strings. Consequently you cannot currently use it to generate UUID values with released code. Nightly builds add support for converting a String generated value to any of TimeZone, Locale, UUID, Currency, so ought to work with that.
>
> Barring that you can easily get the code and create your own ValueGenerator plugin that extends AbstractGenerator to generate UUID objects.

Comment: I think DataNucleus 4.1.7 / 4.2.2 that they released yesterday has this change, so should work out of the box on those. Suggest that you check